# Deleting in Ruby on Rails Routes Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I trying to execute a simple destroy action.

Here is my routes:

```
 post "stories/destroy"
```

The action get_all displays a link to the destroy action.

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', stories_destroy_path(story), method: :delete %></td>
```

And here is the destroy action:

```
def destroy 
    @story = Story.find(story_params[:id])
    if @story.destory
      render :json => {:success => 'true', :message => 'Story deleted!'}
    end 
  end
```

When I hover over the delete link the route it is creating is destroy.1, destroy.2 etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never seen a route declared with a single verb (`post` in your case) but with no second argument. What do you expect it to default to and can you tell me where the default is documented? I can't find any documentation about this in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: That is the question! How do I add the argument for the :id

Comment: I believe the `:id` is implicit, but I was asking about the controller method specification (e.g. `stories#destroy`, as in `post "stories/destroy", to: 'stories#destroy')`

Comment: Also, I'm confused as to why you specified a `post` route but are using a `delete` HTTP action.

Comment: I changed to delete but still having the same issues! I am now using resources :stories to make REST API.

Comment: Ok, well given that you've switched to the default routes, your path would just be `story_path(story)` then.

Comment: Question: What is story_path? How can I view where story_path maps to? It is quite confusing!

Comment: <%= form_for story, url:'create' do |f| %> does not work but <%= form_for story, url:stories_path do |f| %> works!! WHY?

Comment: As for "what is story_path", checkout sections 2.2 and 2.3 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, substituting "stories" for "photos" and "story" for "photo".

Comment: `form_for story, url: 'create'` doesn't work because 'create` isn't a valid path. `form_for story, url: stories_path` "works" because "/stories" is a valid path, although I don't believe `id` will be set in that case. Have you tried just `form_for story` with `link_to 'Delete', method: :delete`?

Answer (score 0):

Update the path to be

```
stories_path(story)
```

Also you should use delete instead of post to be more resourceful:

```
delete "stories"
```

Comment: How did you find about stories_path method and where it maps to? If I run rake routes it does not list that method.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use  **<%= link_to 'Delete', story, method: :delete %>**